# Custom spinner button type="number"

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to custom the appearence of the spinner button because I don't like the basic style which they have.

[image]

I would like to add some Jquery function to show them with a different style, like one image for the '+' and one image for the '-', or some color..

I found this on the web to remove the spinner, its works well ;

```
input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;}
::-webkit-inner-spin-button { -webkit-appearance: none;}
::-webkit-outer-spin-button { -webkit-appearance: none;}
```

But if I want to replace the code too add red color for exemple, it doesnt works ;

```
::-webkit-inner-spin-button { background: red }
```

How can I do that with Jquery ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would look into using some UI kit(Bootstrap UI, Kendo UI, Jquery, etc.). It's going to make your life easier.

Comment: jQuery(':input[type="number"]').css('background-color','red');  do you need something like this ?

Comment: @Mark I don't want to use Bootstrap or Kendo, and I allready Use Jquery, juste I don't know exactly how to make what I want

Comment: @vishwa No, I want to only custom the spinner '+' and '-'

Comment: pls have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/WwfW9/

Comment: @vishwa Thanks you vishwa but I already saw this fiddle, it's better then nothing yes, just It works only in Chrome. 
I know that with Jquery we can make it working with browsers majority